# Mac (CommCenter) seems to want to grab port 500,4500 and redirect to an external IP address?

Tags: networking, mac, port-forwarding

I am obviously quite confused at this. I wanted to run a mini VPN on my Mac to test some network code of some app. I tried to run a docker image that maps ports 500 and 4500 to the running docker image and it failed (port already allocated etc). At first I thought I had it running twice or something but on further investigation I found this:

```
CommCente 3280            rich   16u  IPv4 0xd71591bd29a66d73      0t0    UDP megamac.lan:500->109.249.186.73:500
CommCente 3280            rich   18u  IPv4 0xd71591bd1c25c9b3      0t0    UDP megamac.lan:4500->109.249.186.73:4500
CommCente 3280            rich   24u  IPv6 0xd71591bd205608b3      0t0    UDP [2a01:4c8:e200:126f:dbe8:e17d:2e4a:3a7f]:5060
CommCente 3280            rich   25u  IPv6 0xd71591bd21881213      0t0    TCP [2a01:4c8:e200:126f:dbe8:e17d:2e4a:3a7f]:5060 (LISTEN)
```

Now from my limited understanding of networking, this means that it's listening to those ports and then forwarding to that external IP ? I don't even know who / what that IP address is.

Have I missed something basic ? All I want is to map 500 and 4500 to a docker container. Am I running something on my Mac that allows me to gain remote access if I need to ?

Comment: what command did you run? If its netstat, I'd assume that its listing connections to/from those systems, and the only one in a listening state is TCP\5060. if a port has been created by a program and bound to an interface, no other program can create the same port on the same interface, so your options are to shut down the service on the host that owns those ports or reconfigure the service to use other ports if you wish to use those ports for another application.

Comment: sudo lsof -i -P | grep CommCente